# Unexpected value in lubridate as.numeric using value months in units arg

Tags: r, lubridate

I can not understand the result of using the months value in units arg when I use as.numeric and period in lubridate package.
Maybe it's a bag?

```
a <- period(years = 1, months = 3, days = 1)
as.numeric(a, 'days')
as.numeric(a, 'years')
as.numeric(a, 'months')
```

Result:

```
> as.numeric(a, 'days')
[1] 457.5625
> as.numeric(a, 'years')
[1] 1.252738
> as.numeric(a, 'months')
[1] 0.1043948
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint LMDE

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_AR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=es_AR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_AR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_AR.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=es_AR.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=es_AR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_AR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] dplyr_0.5.0            purrr_0.2.2            readr_1.0.0            tidyr_0.6.1            tibble_1.2            
  [6] ggplot2_2.2.1          tidyverse_1.1.1        pgr_0.0.9002           myutilities_0.0.0.9014 magrittr_1.5          
 [11] lubridate_1.6.0       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.9       plyr_1.8.4        forcats_0.2.0     tools_3.3.2         jsonlite_1.2      gtable_0.2.0      nlme_3.1-128     
 [8] lattice_0.20-34   psych_1.6.12      DBI_0.5-1         RPostgreSQL_0.4-1 parallel_3.3.2    haven_1.0.0       stringr_1.1.0    
[15] httr_1.2.1        xml2_1.1.1        hms_0.3           grid_3.3.2        R6_2.2.0          readxl_0.1.1      foreign_0.8-67   
[22] reshape2_1.4.2    modelr_0.1.0      scales_0.4.1      assertthat_0.1    mnormt_1.5-5      rvest_0.3.2       colorspace_1.3-2 
[29] stringi_1.1.2     lazyeval_0.2.0    munsell_0.4.3     broom_0.4.1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug.  I believe this conversion is done using `lubridate:::seconds_to_unit`, which on lubridate version 1.6.0 looks like this:

```
> lubridate:::seconds_to_unit
function (secs, unit = "second") 
{
    switch(unit, second = secs, minute = secs/60, hour = secs/3600, 
        day = secs/86400, month = secs/(86400 * 365.25)/12, week = secs/(86400 * 
            7), year = secs/(86400 * 365.25), stop("invalid unit ", 
            unit))
}
<environment: namespace:lubridate>
```

Note this part:

```
month = secs/(86400 * 365.25)/12
```

Clearly the idea here is that `86400*365.25` is seconds per year, and dividing this by `12` gives seconds per month.   But it should be:

```
month = secs/((86400 * 365.25)/12)
```

(Note the additional parentheses.)

As a result of this error, the answer you're getting is 144 times smaller than it should be.

---

I believe this is also the cause of this bug: https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/490

(There it's described as giving the reciprocal of the expected result.  That's just because they happened to pick a 12 month interval, so dividing by 144 gives you 1/12 of a month instead.)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I put `> as.numeric(a, "seconds")/(86400 * 365.25)/12
[1] 0.1043948
> as.numeric(a, "seconds")/((86400 * 365.25)/12)
[1] 15.03285`. Thanks I lot.

Comment: You're welcome. :)  I also just submitted a pull request to lubridate that contains the fix: https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/pull/524